# Android gaussian blur very slow on android

Tags: android, image-processing, blur, gaussian, renderscript

I have an image of around 24x24px that i want to zoom to around 720*720. the zoom will produce very pixeled image like :

[image]

and i want to blur it like this to remove the block pixels  :

[image]

I try to use ScriptIntrinsicBlur to blur my Bitmap, but the maximum radius we can set in ScriptIntrinsicBlur is 25 and i need something much more bigger like 250. So i try to run several time ScriptIntrinsicBlur on my bitmap (around 10 times) to have the adequate result, but of course now with all theses loop it's very slow with around 1000ms per image :(

```
  aRS := getRenderScript;
  while aRadius > 0 do begin
    aInput := TJAllocation.JavaClass.createFromBitmap(aRS, aBitmap);
    aOutPut := TJAllocation.JavaClass.createTyped(aRS, aInput.getType());
    aScript :=  TJScriptIntrinsicBlur.javaclass.create(aRS, TJElement.javaclass.U8_4(aRS));
    aTmpRadius := Min(25, aRadius);
    aRadius := aRadius - aTmpRadius;
    ascript.setRadius(aTmpRadius);
    ascript.setInput(aInput);
    ascript.forEach(aOutput);
    aoutput.copyTo(aBitmap);
    ascript := nil;
    aInput := nil;
    aOutPut := nil;
  end;
  aRS := nil;
```

What can I do to improve the speed ?

Comment: You should use a proper interpolation method when zooming in. You are using nearest neighbor interpolation (which just repeats pixel values). Try cubic interpolation or Lanczos interpolation.

Comment: how to do this in android ? remember i start from a 24x24 px image to 720x720 px

Comment: I have no idea about what libraries are available on Android, or how to use them. But interpolation works the same way on any platform, if you want to implement it yourself. Look for the terms I gave in the other comment, even Wikipedia has sample code.

Comment: Have you tried using ScriptIntrinsicResize instead of blur ?